# How to send byte using NSdata

Tags: objective-c, byte, nsdata

I'm new in the area of Objective-C.
My question is, how can I Send a byte format like `b70f` using NSData?

So, basically I have to make a variable first with the value of `b70f` and then write it to the peripheral.

```
[peripheral writeValue:[NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:1] forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

How can I do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of data type is peripherals??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `b70f` is a 16-bit value, something like this should work...

```
uint16_t value = 0xb70f;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:2];
```

This takes advantage that an "array" of two bytes fits into a single 16-bit integer.

If the bytes are in the wrong order, wrap the assignment with `OSSwapInt16()`.

```
uint16_t value = OSSwapInt16(0xb70f);
```

Comment: The `0x` prefix is how to specify a hexadecimal literal.  I think you need to brush up on your C.

Comment: Thank you, I've it almost. But the problem is now, that it must be in 2 bytes order like b7 should be one byte and 0f should be one byte. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Read the last couple lines of my answer.  The macros mentioned will switch the byte order for you.  You may also use `OSSwapInt16()` directly, and that's probably a better answer.

Comment: I've tested it, as you said. You are right, it's actually in the right format, after using  OSSwapInt16() directly. Unfortunately on the other side of peripheral, it receives just in a one byte order and I don't know why.